# Creating a table populated with record counts from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I want to validate that 2 (or more) tables have the same count daily. I figured executing a SELECT count against each table and reporting them as values in their own named column within a temp table would be efficient even if just to eye-ball the numbers in the results window

```
  CREATE TABLE #sync_count (mst_cnt AS varchar(5), info_cnt AS varchar(5));
    INSERT INTO #sync_count (mst_cnt, info_cnt)
    VALUES (
    SELECT Sum(SRV_MST.SRV_MACID) AS mst_cnt FROM SRV_MST,
    SELECT Sum(SRV_INFO.SRV_MACID) AS info_cnt FROM SRV_INFO,
    ))

DELETE #sync_count
```

Desired output

```
SRV_MST | SRV_INFO
===================
  22    | 22
===================
```

Not sure exactly where I went wrong. Any tips? Many thanks

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `#` in a table name, so I removed the PL/SQL tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses around subqueries:

```
CREATE TABLE #sync_count (mst_cnt varchar(5), info_cnt varchar(5));
----------------------------------^ as is not used in table declarations.

INSERT INTO #sync_count (mst_cnt, info_cnt)
    VALUES ( (SELECT Sum(SRV_MST.SRV_MACID) AS mst_cnt FROM SRV_MST),
             (SELECT Sum(SRV_INFO.SRV_MACID) AS info_cnt FROM SRV_INFO)
           );
```

You also had an extra comma before the last paren.

I would strongly, strongly, strongly recommend that you define the counts as *numbers* and not *string*!

```
CREATE TABLE #sync_count (mst_cnt int, info_cnt int);
```

In fact, you can dispense with the table declaration and just use:

```
SELECT (SELECT Sum(SRV_MST.SRV_MACID) FROM SRV_MST) AS mst_cnt,
       (SELECT Sum(SRV_INFO.SRV_MACID) FROM SRV_INFO) AS info_cnt 
INTO #sync_count ;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I did have to change sum to COUNT as SQL complained about incorrect type for the sum operand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as:

```
INSERT INTO #sync_count (mst_cnt, info_cnt)
SELECT
    (SELECT Sum(SRV_MST.SRV_MACID) FROM SRV_MST),
    (SELECT Sum(SRV_INFO.SRV_MACID) FROM SRV_INFO)
```